# Bridging and referencing multiple instances of a ReactNative iOS view

Tags: react-native

I'm bridging to an iOS view, and this view is wrapped into a ReactNative component.

So the view is retrieved using `requireNativeComponent('ViewName', null)`.
e.g.

```
var CircleTableView = requireNativeComponent('CircleTableView', null);
var CircleTableViewManager = NativeModules.CircleTableViewManager;

doStuff() {
    CircleTableViewManager.doStuffInIos();
}

class NativeCircularList extends Component {

render() {
    return <CircleTableView/>
  }
}
```

In my ReactNative main component, I'm using this wrapped component twice.
e.g.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <NativeCircularList/>
          <NativeCircularList/>
        <View>
    )
```

In the iOS RCTViewManager, I keep a reference to the view created in the view() method, so that I can later use it in doStuffInIos().

e.g.

```
@objc(CircleTableViewManager)
class CircleTableViewManager : RCTViewManager {

    var coolCircleTableView: CoolCircleTableView!

    override func view() -> UIView! {

      coolCircleTableView = CoolCircleTableView();

      return coolCircleTableView;
    }

    @objc func doStuffInIos() {
      DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.coolCircleTableView.doStuff()
      }  
    }
}
```

However, RCTViewManager appears to be an application-scoped singleton, meaning that when view() is called for the second instance of the widget, the reference from the first call is present.  In fact, the docs state that a new instance must be returned for each call into view(), which is fine, but I want to be able to use those instances at some point!

Is there a pattern for supporting multiple instances of the same iOS (and/or Android) bridged view?

Thanks